# Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL heroku crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I keep getting this in the heroku log:

```
14-10-30T12:59:51+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-10-30T12:59:51.608050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-10-30T13:00:00.705131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 35211 -c ./co
nfig/unicorn.rb`
2014-10-30T13:00:03.661476+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-10-30T13:00:03.661285 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-10-30T13:00:15.728226+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2014-10-30T13:00:21.655877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

checked pretty much everything all answers in google.

db:setup worked

db:migrate worked

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false is set

it's not only heroku, I also get the same error in local production environment:

```
Macs-MacBook-Pro:v1 mac$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Exiting
```

here is database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  encoding: unicode
  database: s1_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password
```

don't have any problems with local dev environment :(

WHat else can I do ? or how to find the problem ?

Comment: is DATABASE_URL set to a valid database? e.g. does 'psql <DATABASE_URL value>' work?

Comment: yep the databases are created, migrated and should be working